# Spring boot count and save in Json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 classes: `Zone` and `Installation`.

`Installation` is included in `Zone` (every `Zone` have multiple `Installation`s)

I want to create a `Controller` that could give me every `Zone` and its `Installation`s count. Example: {zone1:5, zone2:2 ...} and I want it to have it in a JSON Format.

**Zone.java**

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_zone")
private int idZone;

@Column(nullable=false, name="code")
private Integer code;

private String name;
private String type;

@Column(name = "tenant_id")
private int tenantId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "zone",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Installation> installations;


public Zone() {
}


public Zone(int code, String name, int tenantId, String type, List<Installation> installations) {
  super();
  this.code = code;
  this.name = name;
  this.tenantId = tenantId;
  this.type = type;
  this.installations = installations;
}



public int getIdZone() {
  return this.idZone;
}

public void setIdZone(int idZone) {
  this.idZone = idZone;
}

public Integer getCode() {
  return this.code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
  this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
  return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}

public int getTenantId() {
  return this.tenantId;
}

public void setTenantId(int tenantId) {
  this.tenantId = tenantId;
}

public String getType() {
  return this.type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
  this.type = type;
}

public List<Installation> getInstallations() {
  return this.installations;
}

public void setInstallations(List<Installation> installations) {
  this.installations = installations;
}

public Installation addInstallation(Installation installation) {
  getInstallations().add(installation);
  installation.setZone(this);

  return installation;
}

public Installation removeInstallation(Installation installation) {
  getInstallations().remove(installation);
  installation.setZone(null);

  return installation;
}
```

**Installations.java**

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String code;

private String color;

@Column(name = "gps_lat",nullable= false)
private String gpsLat;

@Column(name = "gps_lon",nullable= false)
private String gpsLon;

private String name;

private String nature;

@Column(name = "outputs_auto_mode")
private byte outputsAutoMode;

@Column(name = "provider_id")
private Integer providerId;

private Integer surface;

@Column(name = "tenant_id")
private int tenantId;

private String type;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "installation")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Device> devices;


// bi-directional many-to-one association to Group
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "installation")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Group> groups;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to Zone
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "zone_id")
private Zone zone;

// bi-directional many-to-many association to InstallationGroup
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "installations")
@JsonIgnore
private List<InstallationGroup> installationGroups;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to Point
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "installation")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Point> points;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to Sonde
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "installation")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Sonde> sondes;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to Station
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "installation")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Station> stations;

public Installation() {
}

public int getId() {
  return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
}

public String getCode() {
  return this.code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
  this.code = code;
}

public String getColor() {
  return this.color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
  this.color = color;
}

public String getGpsLat() {
  return this.gpsLat;
}

public void setGpsLat(String gpsLat) {
  this.gpsLat = gpsLat;
}

public String getGpsLon() {
  return this.gpsLon;
}

public void setGpsLon(String gpsLon) {
  this.gpsLon = gpsLon;
}

public String getName() {
  return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}

public String getNature() {
  return this.nature;
}

public void setNature(String nature) {
  this.nature = nature;
}

public byte getOutputsAutoMode() {
  return this.outputsAutoMode;
}

public void setOutputsAutoMode(byte outputsAutoMode) {
  this.outputsAutoMode = outputsAutoMode;
}

public Integer getProviderId() {
  return this.providerId;
}

public void setProviderId(int providerId) {
  this.providerId = providerId;
}

public Integer getSurface() {
  return this.surface;
}

public void setSurface(int surface) {
  this.surface = surface;
}

public int getTenantId() {
  return this.tenantId;
}

public void setTenantId(int tenantId) {
  this.tenantId = tenantId;
}

public String getType() {
  return this.type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
  this.type = type;
}

public Zone getZone() {
  return this.zone;
}

public void setZone(Zone zone) {
  this.zone = zone;
}

public List<Device> getDevices() {
  return this.devices;
}

public void setDevices(List<Device> devices) {
  this.devices = devices;
}

public Device addDevice(Device device) {
  getDevices().add(device);
  device.setInstallation(this);

  return device;
}

public Device removeDevice(Device device) {
  getDevices().remove(device);
  device.setInstallation(null);

  return device;
}


public List<Group> getGroups() {
  return this.groups;
}

public void setGroups(List<Group> groups) {
  this.groups = groups;
}

public Group addGroup(Group group) {
  getGroups().add(group);
  group.setInstallation(this);

  return group;
}

public Group removeGroup(Group group) {
  getGroups().remove(group);
  group.setInstallation(null);

  return group;
}

public List<InstallationGroup> getInstallationGroups() {
  return this.installationGroups;
}

public void setInstallationGroups(List<InstallationGroup> installationGroups) {
  this.installationGroups = installationGroups;
}

public List<Point> getPoints() {
  return this.points;
}

public void setPoints(List<Point> points) {
  this.points = points;
}

public Point addPoint(Point point) {
  getPoints().add(point);
  point.setInstallation(this);

  return point;
}

public Point removePoint(Point point) {
  getPoints().remove(point);
  point.setInstallation(null);

  return point;
}

public List<Sonde> getSondes() {
  return this.sondes;
}

public void setSondes(List<Sonde> sondes) {
  this.sondes = sondes;
}

public Sonde addSonde(Sonde sonde) {
  getSondes().add(sonde);
  sonde.setInstallation(this);

  return sonde;
}

public Sonde removeSonde(Sonde sonde) {
  getSondes().remove(sonde);
  sonde.setInstallation(null);

  return sonde;
}

public List<Station> getStations() {
  return this.stations;
}

public void setStations(List<Station> stations) {
  this.stations = stations;
}

public Station addStation(Station station) {
  getStations().add(station);
  station.setInstallation(this);

  return station;
}

public Station removeStation(Station station) {
  getStations().remove(station);
  station.setInstallation(null);

  return station;
}
```

*****Updated*****

**`Zone` Repository**

```
public interface ZoneRepository extends JpaRepository<Zone, Integer>{ }
```

**`Installation` Repository**

```
public interface InstallationRepository extends JpaRepository<Installation, Integer> { }
```

**`Zone` Controller**

```java
public class ZoneController {

    @Autowired
    private ZoneRepository zoneRepository;

    @GetMapping("/zones")

    public List<Zone> getAllZones() {
    return zoneRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/zones/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Zone> getZoneById(@PathVariable(value = "id") int zoneId)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Zone zone = zoneRepository.findById(zoneId)
          .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + zoneId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(zone);
    }

    @PostMapping("/zones")
    public Zone createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Zone zone) {
        return zoneRepository.save(zone);
    }

    @PutMapping("/zones/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Zone> updateZone(@PathVariable(value = "id") int zoneId,
         @Valid @RequestBody Zone zoneDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Zone zone = zoneRepository.findById(zoneId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + zoneId));

        //zone.setIdZone(zoneDetails.getIdZone());
        zone.setName(zoneDetails.getName());
        zone.setTenantId(zoneDetails.getTenantId());
        zone.setType(zoneDetails.getType());
        final Zone updatedzone = zoneRepository.saveAndFlush(zone);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedzone);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/zones/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteZone(@PathVariable(value = "id") int zoneId)
         throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Zone zone = zoneRepository.findById(zoneId)
       .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + zoneId));

        zoneRepository.delete(zone);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**`Installation` Controller**

```java
public class InstallationController {
    @Autowired
    InstallationRepository installRepository;


    @GetMapping("/installations")

    public List<Installation> getAllInstallation() {
    return installRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/installations/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Installation> getInstallationById(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Installation install = installRepository.findById(id)
          .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + id));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(install);
    }

    @PostMapping("/installations")
    public Installation createInstallation(@Valid @RequestBody Installation install) {
        return installRepository.save(install);
    }

    @PutMapping("/installations/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Installation> updateInstallation(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id,
         @Valid @RequestBody Installation installDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Installation install = installRepository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Installation not found for this id :: " + id));

        install.setName(installDetails.getName());
        install.setCode(installDetails.getCode());
        install.setColor(installDetails.getColor());
        install.setGpsLat(installDetails.getGpsLat());
        install.setGpsLon(installDetails.getGpsLon());
        install.setNature(installDetails.getNature());
        install.setOutputsAutoMode(installDetails.getOutputsAutoMode());
        install.setSurface(installDetails.getSurface());
        install.setType(installDetails.getType());
        install.setTenantId(installDetails.getTenantId());
        install.setZone(installDetails.getZone());

        final Installation updatedInstallation = installRepository.saveAndFlush(install);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedInstallation);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/installations/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteInstallation(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id)
         throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Installation install = installRepository.findById(id)
       .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Installation not found for this id :: " + id));

        installRepository.delete(install);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `controller` and `seviceImpl`

Comment: Done i updated the subject

Comment: you can not mention your problem above

Comment: And fist you want know meaning of `@JsonIgnore -> it's ignored both when reading JSON into Java objects, and when writing Java objects into JSON`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood this correctly what you want is something like the following in your `ZoneController` :

```java
@GetMapping("/zones-installation-count")
  public Map<String, Integer> getAllZonesInstalationCount() {
  return zoneRepository.findAll().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Zone::getName, (zone) -> zone.getInstallations().size()));
}
```

Comment: just i changed "getIdZone" with "getName"

Comment: Excuse me sir i have a question : i want to change the Json format to { name : zone1 , count : 5 } how can i do that

Comment: Then you need to create a class (say `ZoneDto`) with those two attributes (`name` and `count`) and map each `Zone` to an instance of that class. You need to replace `Map<String, Integer>` with `List<ZoneDto>`.

Comment: i didn't understand the ZoneDto thing , why creating a new claass ? can i use the Zone Class Directly ? otherwise it would be helpful to write the Necessary code

Comment: No, you can't reuse `Zone` since it does not include a `count` attribute now.  Additionally, `Zone` is your entity and you should avoid using entities as the model of your API.

Answer (score 3):

You will never get installations value in response

Because of below portions ->

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "zone",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Installation> installations;
```

@JsonIgnore will ignore all your installations data for every request

Remove @JsonIgnore , then you will get all those installations property